# How can i get an ID as parameter from an URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I want to route the following URL;

```
/anything/anything-v43243-anything
```

How can i route this to a specific controller and action with that id as parameter?
The text "anything" has to be a text with at least a few characters. The id needs to start with the letter "v".
I want this to create friendly URL's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom route for that and appropriate constraints for the different parts:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "myroute",
    "anything/{x}-{id}-{y}",
    new { controller = "SomeController", action = "SomeAction" },
    new { x = "[a-z]+", y = "[a-z]+", id = @"\d+" }
);
```

Comment: I only need the id, the rest is not important; only for friendly URL purposes. and the id needs to start with the letter "v"

Comment: Even if it is not important you need to include it in the route pattern as shown in my answer: `"anything/{x}-{id}-{y}"`. As far as the id must start with the letter `v` is concerned, simply adapt the regular expression for the id constraint. In my example it accepts only integer values but if you want something else make sure you write the corresponding regular expression.